# Cloudflare CNAME cloud icon isn't showing, does this affect anything?

Tags: dns, cloudflare, cname

I have set up a new DNS record and it doesn’t show the cloud Icon for a CNAME record.

I am wondering because the subdomain also isn’t working, so I was wondering if the icon not displaying has any effect on the subdomain not working?

[image: Screenshot of Cloudflare]

As you can see from the screenshot, shop and shop1 don’t have an icon.

Thanks in advance for your help. :slight_smile:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out from cloudflare why it wouldn't show.

The reason is that the place where the alias is pointing to is already on cloudflare.
So you cannot determine the http/s status.